# Travis CI build passing but status bar still showing error

Tags: java, travis-ci

Hi so my current build is passing which you can view here: https://travis-ci.org/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

But if you go to my repository here:https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

and look at the travis CI status bar it still says there is a build error. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nvm, It just takes like 20 minutes to update.

Comment: You are allowed to delete your own question.

Comment: I had the same question and found the answer useful.

Comment: I second that, this was helpful